# Backup MySQL database and gzip

Tags: gzip, mysql

I'm trying to get a little more usefulness out of my MySQL backups. I'm wanting to gzip my backup when it's completed from a cron job. Here's the script I have so far to do the backup.

```
#!/bin/sh
date=`date -Iminutes`
mysqldump --all-databases > /var/sqlbackup/sqlbackup-$date.sql -pmypassword
find /var/sqlbackup/ -mtime 3 | xargs rm
```

Any help would be beneficial, even if it's a pointer on how to do it better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a backup/maintenance script I use:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
#backup all mysql databases
# list MySQL databases and dump each
DIR=
DATESTAMP=$(date +%Y%m%d)
DB_USER=
DB_PASS=

# remove old backups
find ${DIR} -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;


DB_LIST=`mysql -u $DB_USER -p"$DB_PASS" -e'show databases;'`
DB_LIST=${DB_LIST##Database}
for DB in $DB_LIST;
do
  FILENAME=${DIR}${DB}-${DATESTAMP}.sql.gz
  mysqldump -u $DB_USER -p"$DB_PASS" --opt --flush-logs $DB | gzip > $FILENAME
done

mysqlcheck -u $DB_USER -p"$DB_PASS" --all-databases > /root/mysql_backups/check_errors-${DATESTAMP}.log
```

This script generates an individual gzipped backup of each database so that you don't have to restore the entire server's databases if there's just a problem with one DB.  It also includes some mysql check sanity and finds old database backups and deletes them.

To restore, as requested:

I've had to restore a couple of times. It happens.

```
gunzip backup_file.sql.gz
mysql -u <username> -p  <database_name> < backup_file.sql
```

There's probably a more 'one line' way of doing it... but that's how it's worked for me.

Comment: I really like this script, it's fast and gets right to what we need for the backup side. Might you be able to share the flip side where it's exploding the gzips and restoring the DB? Or haven't you had to worry about that!

Comment: Editing answer to show restores...

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
date=`date -Iminutes`
find /var/sqlbackup/ -name 'sqlbackup-*' -mtime +2 -delete
mysqldump --all-databases -pmypassword | gzip > /var/sqlbackup/sqlbackup-$date.sql.gz
```

You can pipe to `gzip` to compress.

I moved the find to before the mysqldump.  I'm not sure how big your databases are, but it'll help to keep disk usage down and avoid any space issues.

It's usually better to use `-mtime +2` instead of `-mtime 3` to affect anything older than two days rather than files exactly 3 days old.  This way if your cron misses a day, you don't get older files missed by the delete.

Personally I prefer to restrict `find` to a name pattern, too, to make sure you aren't deleting anything unexpectedly.

The `-delete` option in find is helpful if you don't want to use `xargs`.  Both ways will work, but I  prefer to use fewer commands when possible.

Comment: Good point on the `-mtime +2`. I'll look at improving this process!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `gzip /var/sqlbackup/sqlbackup-$date.sql` to the end of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date=`date -Iminutes`
mysqldump --all-databases -pmypassword | gzip > /var/sqlbackup/sqlbackup-$date.gz
```

Comment: That doesn't delete outdated backups, like the asker's example does.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever looked into irsync by R-FX networks?

A great little script that will allow you to take hot copies and gzips of your databases and send it to a remote server. :)